# call a function after selecting an option from datalist

Tags: html, angularjs

```js
$scope.empobj=[{first_name:"new",last_name:"sjkk",id:"2"},{first_name:"new",last_name:"sjkk",id:"3"},{first_name:"new",last_name:"sjkk",id:"4"}];

$scope.selectedemp1= function(id){
console.log(id);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputemployee" ng-model="empname" list="suggestions"   > 
                    
<datalist id="suggestions" >
    <option ng-repeat="emp in empobj" ng-change= "selectedemp1(emp.id)" value="{{emp.first_name}} {{emp.last_name}}"></option>
    
</datalist>
```

Hi, This is a part of my code I am trying to call a function and passing the id of selected option(record) but it is not calling the function. I tried with ng-click also. what am I missing? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need **`<select>`** instead of data-list, also use **`ng-model`** variable

**`DEMO`**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);

app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){

$scope.empobj=[{first_name:"new",last_name:"sjkk",id:"2"},{first_name:"new",last_name:"sjkk",id:"3"},{first_name:"new",last_name:"sjkk",id:"4"}];

$scope.selectedemp1= function(id){
console.log(id);
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputemployee" ng-model="empname" list="suggestions"   > 
                    
<select ng-options="emp as  emp.last_name for  emp in empobj" 
   ng-model="selected" ng-change="selectedemp1(selected.id)"></select>
   
 </body>
```

Comment: but the options are not showing for the input field. It is showing separate select field

Comment: its just a sample, you might need to change according to your need

Comment: Both first_name and last_name are needed and for the input, field suggestions are needed (not select option). I am new to angularjs. please clarify.Thanks in advance

Comment: i am not getting your question